# How to convert gregorian days to gregorian date

Tags: javascript, datetime, django-templates, erlang

I store gregorian days with some other data in my table.
I get these days via the following Erlang commands:

```
{Date, _} = calendar:now_to_datetime(now()).
GDays = calendar:date_to_gregorian_days(Date).
```

Let's take this value as an example: GDays = 736202.

I have build a website in Cowboy with ErlyDTL for my views.
Now I want to present these gregorian days in a date format. (2015 august 28).

I use following code to get my data out of a list in my view:

```
{% for item in list %}
  {{item.1}} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried the following command `{{item.1|date:" D d M Y"}}` but I get an error:

> Unexpected date parameter: 736202

Now how can I convert this gregorian days to a datetime in erlyDTL or javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is information on calculating Gregorian dates here: [*Converting Gregorian Date to Gregorian Days*](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62338.html). If you need help implementing the algorithm, just ask. Once you have a Date object, there are many questions here on how to format it.

Comment: How can I do this in the reverse way and with the days count started in the year 0 (gregorian). I have the number of days which are being calculated in your reference. Now I want that number calculated back to a datestamp.

Comment: When I do 736202 / 365.25, I get 2015.6112251882273.
Now I get stuck because I don't know how to get the months and days out of it.

Comment: The epoch for Gregorian days should be 15 October 1582. Adding 736,202 days to that gives 10 Jun 3598. If you use an epoch of 1 Jan 0001, then you'll get  27 Aug 2016. Subtract a year if starting in year 0 (which doesn't really make sense). Most places warn against calculating Gregorian dates before the start of the Gregorian calendar, though I guess you can use any epoch you like.

Comment: I don't understand this math becaus the gregorian calendar starts at 1 january 0000. Erlang gives me (see commands above) an number which are the number of days since 1 january 0000. I think what you're saying is in the julian calendar (Am I correct?). Can you give me the algorithm for this reverse calculation so I can easilier understand?

Comment: The Julian calendar starts on 1 January, 4713 BC so no, not Julian days. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the algorithm that I needed. I made it in javascript in a very simple way what is good enough for now, so don't be critical ;).
There is no support for leap years.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function date(n){
        // Calculate the year.
        var year = Math.round(n / 365.2425 - 0.5);
        // Get the remainder of the year calculation.
        var dec = Math.round(((n * 10000) / 365.2425) - (year * 10000));
        // Multiply remainder with 365.2425.
        var day = Math.round((dec * 365.25) / 10000);
        // Search which month and day it is.
        if(day <= 30){
          return day.toString().concat(" januari ").concat(year);
        }else if(day <= 58){
          return (day - 30).toString().concat(" februari ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 89){
          return (day - 58).toString().concat(" maart ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 119){
          return (day - 89).toString().concat(" april ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 150){
          return (day - 119).toString().concat(" mei ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 180){
          return (day - 150).toString().concat(" juni ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 211){
          return (day - 180).toString().concat(" juli ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 242){
          return (day - 211).toString().concat(" augustus ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 272){
          return (day - 242).toString().concat(" september ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 303){
          return (day - 272).toString().concat(" oktober ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 333){
          return (day - 303).toString().concat(" november ").concat(year.toString());
        }else if(day <= 364){
          return (day - 333).toString().concat(" december ").concat(year.toString());
        }else{
          return "error";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      document.write(date(736205));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation here: [*http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html*](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/calendar.html)

Erlang bases Gregorian days on an epoch of 1 January, 0 and provides an example: 1 Jan 1970 is 719528. So the epoch is day 0.

The following functions convert Date objects to Gregorian days and back. They return correct values according to the single example in the documentation, but convert 736202 to 27 Aug 2015 not 28 Aug. Perhaps you're using UTC not local time. Anyway, I think there's enough here for you to work it out.

```js
/* @param {Date} [date] - Date object to be converted
** @returns {number} - whole days since 1 January 0 to d
**
** epoch date must set year separately as in many implementations
** new Date(0,0,1) returns 1 Jan 1900, not 1 Jan 0000
*/
function dateToGregorianDays(date) {

  // Create a Date object for 0000-Jan-01 (months are zero based)
  var epoch = new Date(0,0,1);

  // Set the epoch to year 0 as in the above some browsers will
  // create a date for 1900 not 0, even though 0 was passed in
  epoch.setFullYear(0);

  // Copy the passed in Date so it's not modified by next step
  var e = new Date(+date);

  // Set the time part of the copied date to 00:00:00, which
  // helps to calculate whole days
  e.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  // In mathematic operations, dates are converted to their time value
  // which is milliseconds, so get the difference in milliseconds between
  // the two dates and divide by milliseconds per day. Round to remove 
  // fractional parts caused occasionally over daylight saving boundaries
  // to get whole day count between the two dates and return it
  return Math.round((e - epoch)/8.64e7);
}

/* @param {number} [days] - Gregorian day number
** @returns {Date} - Based on whole days since 1 January 0
**
**      0 -> 1 Jan 0000
** 719528 -> 1 Jan 1970
*/
function gregorianDaysToDate(days) {

  // Create a date for 0000-Jan-01
  var epoch = new Date(0,0,1);
  epoch.setFullYear(0);

  // Add the number of days to the date
  // epoch.getDate() could be replaced by 1 since that's what
  // the date was set to just above
  epoch.setDate(epoch.getDate() + days);

  // Return the date
  return epoch;
}

/* Simple function to return a date string as dd-MMM-yyyy
** @param {Date} [date] - Date to format
** @returns {string} - formatted string for date
*/
function formatDateDMY(date) {
 
  // Month names
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

  // Add leading zero to single digit days
  // Get the month name for the month (zero indexed, 0 is Jan)
  // Add leading zeros to years with less than 4 digits
  // Use '-' as separator
  return ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' +
         months[date.getMonth()] + '-' +
         ('000' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-4);
}

// Create an alias for the above function to save typing
var fd = formatDateDMY;

// Gregorian days for 01-Jan-1970
document.write(dateToGregorianDays(new Date(1970,0,1)) + '<br>'); // 719528

// Gregorian calendar date for 719528 formatted as dd-MMM-yyyy
document.write(fd(gregorianDaysToDate(719528)) + '<br>')          // 01 Jan 1970

// Gregorian calendar date for 0 formatted as dd-MMM-yyyy
document.write(fd(gregorianDaysToDate(0)) + '<br>');              // 01 Jan 0000

// Gregorian calendar date for 736202 formatted as dd-MMM-yyyy
document.write(fd(gregorianDaysToDate(736202)) + '<br>');         // 27 Aug 2015

// Gregorian days for 28-Aug-2015
document.write(dateToGregorianDays(new Date(2015,7,28)));         // 736203
```

Comment: The number 736202 is actually august 27th ;)

Comment: I don't understand what the code does and how it computes the values.